# How to create a gameboard for Ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I'm creating a game using the Ionic framework.

There is a standard gameboard of say 11x11 square tiles. Ionic's grid system uses flexbox to lay things out. This app will run on various devices so the gameboard will need to scale up and down.

So how do I create a grid of squares using flexbox that is responsive?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/magician11/bp6v3pa3/2/

Or do I abandon the flexbox layout and go with `display: table;` using something like http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/3/light/

Thanks.